# ZF1 Order By 3 clauses

Tags: zend-framework

$select->order(array('a.pay DESC', 'a.payDate ASC', 'a.insertDate DESC'));

I order my query that way, but when I see results, actually a.insertDate has no role in my result order listing.

I want to achieve order when paid accounts (a.pay > 0) are in the first position and the oldest paid account is in first place.. Then after paid account will be listed accounts, which should be ordered by a.insertDate DESC (meaning newer accounts will be placed after paid). I tried with a.id DESC no a.insertDate DESC, but nothing happended at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

`$select->order(array('a.pay DESC','isnull(a.payDate) ASC', 'a.payDate ASC',  'a.insertDate DESC'));`